# How to change the Markup of a asp.net page serverside (from .cs file)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks in advance.

We need to include or exclude IE conditional statements (which are in the header of the page) depending upon if a method(from the code behind) returns true or false. The Method is written in the code behind so if    `IfBrowserIsMobile()`    returns true , Markup related to IE conditional statement should not be present. 
        How do we achieve this ? 
The Mark-up(in the header) is as follows-

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lt-ie9.css" media="screen"/>
    <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an element which itself doesn't emit any markup, such as a `PlaceHolder`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ieLogic">
    <!-- your client-side markup here -->
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then in server-side code, just set its visibility depending on your condition:

```
if (IfBrowserIsMobile())
    isLogic.Visible = false;
```

Generally you don't *change* the markup from server-side code, but you can conditionally show/hide different parts of the markup.

Comment: Hi @David . I have been using the above answer , just wanted to know if we could have multiple placeholders

Comment: @NitinKumarMishra: Of course.  You can place as many controls on your page as you want.

Answer (score 4):

Include a `literal` control in head section of your aspx page and then in code behind you can set the `Text` property of this control to anything you like. This text could be html or non-html text.  You can have as many such controls in the head section as you feel is necessary for your requirements.

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

In your situation you can include following code also in Page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack && !IfBrowserIsMobile())
  {
      Literal1.Text  = "<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lt-ie9.css" media="screen"/>
    <![endif]-->";

  }

}
```

If you want to emit JavaScript using a `Literal` control then use code-behind like below. The important thing is to include opening and closing script tags in this case.

```
Literal1.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hello sir');</script>";
```

Comment: Thanks @sunil . Does this hold true for <body> scetion as well ? We need to the same thing - Include separate .js files if Methods returns true or false.

Comment: Yes you can include this anywhere in the page. But just remember that you need to set its Text to a valid value. For example, you may need to include opening and closing `script` tags if you are setting it's value to some JavaScript and if html then you will need to use correct html tags.